# Light Up (Akari), but on a real projective plane!

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, real-projective-plane

This is a Light Up (aka Akari) puzzle, except it is on what is called a real projective plane. A real projective plane is, simply put, just a Möbius strip with a single edge except for the fact that the opposite open edges are also glued together. This is different from a Klein Bottle because a Klein Bottle is a Möbius strip glued into a cylinder.

Some info about Light Up/Akari:

> Light Up (Japanese: 美術館 *bijutsukan*, art gallery) which is also known as Akari (明かり *akari*, light) is a logic puzzle published by Nikoli in which players must place bulbs on a black and white rectangular grid such that no two bulbs shine light on each other.
>
> A number on a square tells you how many bulbs surround the square **orthogonally**.
>
> The goal is to eventually fill up the grid with light.

The puzzle:

---

[image]

---

Here is a coordinate system that I came up with if it would be helpful to reference it:

[image]

---

I can confirm that the solution to this puzzle is in fact unique.

<sub>*Yay, the first [real-projective-plane](/questions/tagged/real-projective-plane) puzzle!*</sub>

Comment: Could you explain the "real projective plane" criteria in non-mathematical language?  How does it affect the puzzle.  What is different from a typical Akari puzzle?
Your description of the "real projective plane" does not make sense to me, nor does it tell me how it changes the puzzle's rules.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I could edit it to include that info, yes

Comment: If the puzzle has enough empty squares, the Akari rule is ambiguous: it isn't clear if a bulb is allowed to illuminate itself.

Comment: Penpa+ link: http://tinyurl.com/2d9pggfz Select `composite` tab to insert light bulbs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this works:

> [image]

> Each yellow square in the grid is a lamp, labeled a through n. The solution was actually surprisingly straightforward, there need to be four lamps surrounding the black square in H3, and from there everything followed naturally - at each stage there was another black square whose lamps had only one possible placement. See the following images for a step by step solution:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]